# How to convey the message of 'organising the cloud' to users?

Tags: design-patterns, gui-design, copywriting

https://datkey.com is a service we are launching in the near future and I got great input from my prior request so hope a new page connects with users better.

Any tips on how to convey to users the message of organizing the cloud.

Best

Comment: How does the name "DatKey" relate to what the service does?

Comment: With javascript disabled, your front page is currently a blank screen; the best written message in the world is useless if people don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

While your new site is better designed, I would still recommend getting a visual designer to spend a few hours on it. Small details like Times being used here and there and the application itself looking fairly hodge-podge could be fixed quickly (for instance, if I got my hands on it I'd have it cleaned up in about 2 hours).

As for the copy: your writing is still very high level. It's good in the sense that you're not using any technobabble or buzzwords that would confuse users, but it's also still too vague. What are personal folders? What does it mean to share my favourite web content?

Try to get more specific. **What does this service do exactly?** How will I use it? Walk me through what to expect when I sign up - in plain English, like what you'd say if your mom asked you how it worked.

I don't know who makes DatKey. It doesn't say anywhere whether this is just some kid in his basement, a product from a successful company, a startup, or a hackathon project. You should add an "about" page so I can verify your integrity before committing personal information to your cloud. Cloud software still faces a wall of privacy and trust issues so you should invest in ensuring that people can trust you.

37signals has some great examples: [their story](http://37signals.com/about), showing their history and indicating they've been around for a while; [their customers](http://basecamphq.com/customers), using social proof to show you that others trust them (so why shouldn't you?); [a transparent, simple privacy policy](http://basecamphq.com/privacy) communicating what you can expect to happen with your data after you sign up; even a [customer happiness report](http://smiley.37signals.com/) showing you that their customer support is excellent.

Consider those things and spend some time writing some light-weight pages that reflect those things about your service. It'll help your believability.

Comment: Would love to have your direct input to the site! My contact is Ronaktal@gmail .